# Python creating range 000 to 999

Tags: python, list, range

I am writing a Python code using a bin number then create a list of numbers like this

```
bin = "377731"
range(00000, 99999)

for i in range(len(bin)):
    target = open('{0}.txt'.format(bin), 'a') ## a will append, w will over-wri$
    target.write("{0}{1}000".format(bin,i) + "\n")
    target.close()
```

The problem that the Python shows the list like this

> 3777311000

and i need it to write it like that

> 3777310000100

Also the script stop after reaching the number 5

Any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things in your code that needs to be changed:

- You have defined `bin` to be a string with a value `377731`. The length of this string is 6, which is why your loop stops after 5.
- Also, `bin` is a built-in function in python, so it is good not to use it as a name for a variable.
- Opening and closing the file in the loop is a overkill.

Try this instead:

```
bin_suffix = "377731"
target = open('{0}.txt'.format(bin_suffix), 'a') ## a will append, w will over-wri$
for i in range(99999):
    target.write('{}{}'.format(bin_suffix, str(i).zfill(7)) + "\n")
target.close()
```

[`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) is a string function that fills the specified length of the string with zeros. In your case, you need 7 digits after `377731`, so you specify 7 as the argument for `zfill`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give a format specifier, so instead of `{1}` in your format string, use `{1:04}` if you want four digits with zero padding on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `len(bin)`, but just `bin`. Then it doesn't stop at 5.